# Outer list is cleared after clearing inner list

Tags: python, list

In the following snippet, I append a list, `x` to another list `u` and the clear `x`. However, as you can see in the output, after clearing `x`, the second list, `u` is also cleared.

```
a = array([1,2,3,4])
x = []
u = []
for i in np.nditer(a):
    x.append(i.item())
u.append(x)
print("before x.clear(), u=", u)
x.clear()
print("after x.clear(), u=", u)
```

Output

```
before x.clear(), u= [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
after x.clear(), u= [[]]
```

What is the reason? I expect that by using `append` a copy of `x` is appended to `u`. How can I prevent `u` to be cleared after clearing `x`?

Comment: "I expect that by using append a copy of x"...your expectation is wrong. It's a reference to `x`. If you want a copy, you must explicitly copy it (`u.append(x.copy())`).

Comment: @JamesMcPherson, in this example, `x` is a simple one-dimensional list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. You don't need a deep copy for that. A simple `.copy()` suffices.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson no! `x = y` is not a shallow copy, it *isn't a copy at all*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark really answered this in the comments, but just for completeness, here's the working code using `x.copy()` doing what you asked for...

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
x = []
u = []
for i in np.nditer(a):
    x.append(i.item())
u.append(x.copy())
print("before x.clear(), u=", u)
x.clear()
print("after x.clear(), u=", u)
```

Output:

```
before x.clear(), u= [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
after x.clear(), u= [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```